# If Else statement in loop doesnt work how to suppose to

Tags: javascript

This is a very weird and basic problem but I cant seem to find out why it behaves likes this.

Basically this is a piece of code that animates circles on a a screen, when my mouse hovers over a circle the function should use the If statement if not the Else statement.

When I try to run it it shows this when hovering my mouse over a circle:

```
4309canvas.js:151 else false
canvas.js:127 if true
99canvas.js:151 else false
canvas.js:127 if true
99canvas.js:151 else false
canvas.js:127 if true
99canvas.js:151 else false
canvas.js:127 if true
99canvas.js:151 else false
canvas.js:127 if true
99canvas.js:151 else false
```

This is the code

```
function animate() {
    //Animate slower, less stress
    setTimeout(function () {
        //Animate, animate function
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        //clear canvas
        c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
        //Animate every circle
        //circle in length = 100
        for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {

                //When Mouse in circle and I higher then displayInfo
                if ((((distance(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, mouse.x, mouse.y)) < circles[i].radius)) && (i < displayInfo)) {
                    console.log("if",((((distance(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, mouse.x, mouse.y)) < circles[i].radius)) && (i < displayInfo)))
                    //In circle
                }
                else  {
                    console.log("else",((((distance(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, mouse.x, mouse.y)) < circles[i].radius)) && (i < displayInfo)))
                    //Outside of circle
                }

                //update canvas
                circles[i].update();
        }
    }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

And this is the 'distance' function

```
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    let xDistance = x2 - x1;
    let yDistance = y2 - y1;
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDistance, 2) + Math.pow(yDistance, 2));
}
```

EDIT:

Now I know why it behaves like it does. I generate 100 circles and when hovering over 1 circle, it goes in the IF-statement for 1 time and 99 times in the else statement. Because the other circles are not hoverd. So What i what is got: check every circle when mouse is hovering
What i need: When mouse is leaving the only the hoverd circle > give alert
How should I do this?

Comment: I think its because you are console logging in a `for loop` ? Probably not all circle is within your mouse hover ? I guess. Also its more efficient to only declare your conditional check once for each loop instead of writing them repetitively. It will make your code easier to read as well

Comment: It might help you understand what's happening better if you also output the value of `i` for each iteration of the loop.  It looks like you probably have multiple circles here, and you're inside some of them, but outside others.  It's not entirely clear to me what you're expected result is.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Thank you for the comments, Now I know why it behaves like it does. I generate 100 circles and when hovering over 1 circle, it goes in the IF-statement for 1 time and 99 times in the else statement. Because the other circles are not hoverd. So What i what is got: check every circle when mouse is hovering
What i need: When mouse is leaving the only the hoverd circle > give alert
How should I do this?

Comment: @dev_junwen Please check the comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track with variable and check to see if it is different. Something like the following.

```
// default state, not hovered
let circleActive = -1
function animate() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let currentActive = -1
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      // only do the checks if not found yet
      if (currentActive === -1 && (((distance(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, mouse.x, mouse.y)) < circles[i].radius)) && (i < displayInfo)) {
         // found, set what was found
         currentActive = i
      }
      circles[i].update();
    }
    // if numbers differ, state has changed.
    if (currentActive!==circleActive) { // not in same circle
      if (currentActive===-1) { // not in another circle
        console.log("Moved out")
      } else if (circleActive !== -1) { // moved one circle to another
        console.log("Moved in: ", currentActive, ". Moved out:", circleActive)
      } else { // moved into a circle
        console.log("Moved in")
      }
      circleActive = currentActive
    }
  }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code it definitely helped me understand the concept better. I got a question about ' if (currentActive===-1) {
        console.log("Moved out") ' part.  'currentActive' could never be '-1'  because when you hover over it it gets assigned the 'i' value, right? When use this piece of code it only displays 'moved in' in the log and not the 'moved out'

Comment: Well is it moving into a different circle? from one circle to another? I assumed gaps so it would be -1 when not in it.

Comment: Added another if statement which might be what you are talking about

Comment: Yes there is are gaps between circles. I implemented your unedited code and it just console logged 'moved in' . So i checked what I tought was wrong with it and I found out that 'curentActive' is never '-1' (   "   if (currentActive===-1)  "  ). Because when hovering over a circle that variable is changed with ' currentActive = i;'

Comment: And when nothing is hovered it should not find anything and not go into the if and the `let currentActive = -1` should be default.

Comment: Oh crap you have `requestAnimationFrame(animate);` which is doing a revursive call and the variable is set inside of it.... I thought it was an interval. You need `let circleActive = -1` defined outside.